# "Орел – означало Евангелие от Иоанна, Телец – Евангелие от Луки..."?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

> Круг символизировал Вселенную, Божественную силу. Например, в одном
> случае в центре него восседал Христос, в окружении четырех медальонов
> – каждое с символическим изображением. Орел – означало Евангелие от
> Иоанна, Телец – Евангелие от Луки, Лев – от Марка и Ангел от Матфея.

Евангелие ли означал символ? Почему "означал**о**"?

Можно ли так сказать, если тот или иной символ означал евангелиста?

> Символы относит к евангелистам уже Ириней Лионский; Матфей – человек,
> Марк – орел, Лука – вол, Иоанн – лев.
>
> Блаженный Иероним предлагает распределение символов, принятое у нас в
> настоящее время: Матфей – человек, Марк – лев, Лука – телец, Иоанн –
> орел.

[**источник**](https://azbyka.ru/simvoly-evangelistov)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> «...восседал Христос, в окружении четырех медальонов – каждое с символическим изображением. Орел – означало Евангелие от Иоанна, Телец – Евангелие от Луки, Лев – от Марка и Ангел от Матфея.»

Евангелие ли означал символ? Почему "означало"?

*... восседал Христос, в окружении четырех медальонов — каждый с символическим изображением: орёл означал Евангелие от Иоанна, телец — от Луки, лев — от Марка и ангел — от Матфея.*

Можно ли так сказать, если тот или иной символ означал евангелиста?

Лучше — соотносил с евангелистом, а если означал, то «Евангелие от». Каждый в силу своего чувства и умения выразил, придав особую окраску слову Божьему, своё отношение ко Христу: у Матфея Иисус более человек, у Марка — сражающийся лев, Лука подчёркивает жертвенность, Иоанн — земной путь Христа как небожителя.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, правильный род "потерян" начиная со слов "каждое с символическим изображением" — и далее везде.

Comment: Спасибо. А что вот с этим: *Евангелие ли означал символ? Можно ли так сказать, если тот или иной символ означал евангелиста?*

Comment: На мой взгляд, так говорить нельзя. А как правильно - увы, не знаю, не моя сфера.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю согласовать род таким образом:
**Круг символизировал Вселенную, Божественную силу. Например, в одном случае в центре него восседал Христос, окруженный четырьмя медальонами – каждый с символическим изображением. Орел означал Евангелие от Иоанна, Телец – Евангелие от Луки, Лев – от Марка и Ангел – от Матфея.**

**Изображение** (или образ) – это **символ для евангелиста**. Поэтому правильно, как мне кажется, будет так:

Символы относит к евангелистам уже Ириней Лионский; для Матфея – человек, для Марка – орел, для Луки – вол, для Иоанна – лев.
Блаженный Иероним предлагает распределение символов, принятое у нас в настоящее время: для Матфея – человек, для Марка – лев, для Луки – телец, для Иоанна – орел.